# Filter HTML Table using multiple values separated by Comma using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a filter code which is working fine if i give a single value , but i have more than 100+ values in my table, and i have to search for two or three value in the table at same time, so i planned to use comma for that, like in a single search box i will write the values i have to search in a table column in a comma separated fashion.

SO currently it is working, but it is not filtering when i give comma, Since am new to this scripting and web development, Can anyone help me.

```js
$('#tblfiles').dataTable({
  "search": {
    "smart": true,
    "regex": true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<div id="nam"></div>
<br>

<table id="tblfiles">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>StDID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>pooe</td>
      <td>country1</td>
      <td>Sgyt13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>country2</td>
      <td>P5372</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>country3</td>
      <td>P5972</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So here i have to fetch rows which contain Name as AAA and BBB, so instead on searching and getting value one by one, in search bar i have to give AAA, BBB .. so that it will fetch both corresponding rows to me.

[image: ImageofJSfiddle]

So here it replaces the first % but not the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Regex Search

The [DataTables Search Option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search) supports regex as a search input.
If you'll disable [smart search](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.smart), and only enable [regex search](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.regex), you can use the regex syntax to lookup multiple values in the table.

This might work for you as is since you can look up multiple values like this: `country1|country2`

```js
$('#tblfiles').dataTable({
  'search': {
    'smart': false,
    'regex': true
  }
});
```

### Exact Match

If you'll search for `country1|country2`, the table will find all items that **contain** either `country1` or `country2`. Using `^` and `$` to specify where the match should be, doesn't work with dataTables as expected.

If you want to make `country1|country2` return an exact match, simulating the [`^` and `$` use](https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors), you can wrap the search term with `\\b`, which in this case, works similar to `^` and `$`.

```js
// exact match
const regex = '\\b(' + searchTerm + ')\\b';
```

#### Using commas as delimiters

If you want to use commas as delimiters instead of the regex's default of `|`, you can use the same function to replace all commas in the search term to pipes. This way, your users will use commas to search multiple terms at the same time instead of `|`:

```js
// comma delimiter
const searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, '|');
```

#### Examples (with Exact Match enabled)

- **Search:** `country1,country2`
- **Result:** Will return country1 and country2 specifically

---

- **Search:** `country[1-2][0-9]`
- **Result:** Will return all countries between country10 and country 29

---

- **Search:** `o.*`
- **Result:** Will return all rows containing a string that starts with o. Without adding the `.*`, the search will look for an exact match for o (surrounded by something that is not a word) and will return nothing.

**The main difference is if the search regex is strict or loose**

```js
const table = $('#tblfiles');

/* NOT IMPORTANT FOR ANSWER */
/* This is here just to generate data in the table */
const tableBody = table.find('tbody');
for (const x of Array(100).keys()) {
  tableBody.append(`<tr>
  <td>${ x }</td>
  <td>${ chance.name() }</td>
  <td>country${ x }</td>
  <td>${ chance.string({ length: 4, alpha: true, numeric: true }) }</td>
  </tr>`)
}
/* ANSWER CONTINUE HERE */


$('#tblfiles').dataTable({
  'search': {
    'smart': false,
    'regex': true
  }
});

// This is used to force the search value to search whole words.
// This makes sure that searching for `country1|country2` will
// still find an exact match
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
  const searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, '|');
  const regex = '\\b(' + searchTerm + ')\\b';
  table.DataTable().rows().search(regex, true, false).draw();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  padding: 2em;
}

.dataTables_length {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.1.7/chance.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<div id="nam"></div>
<br>

<table id="tblfiles" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>StDID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So , this is working fine , but if i search like *.3 , it should retrieve country3 right , but it's not fetching that result

Comment: and is there any way i can replace this .* with other special chars

Comment: @GowriLakshmi `*.3` is not the right syntax so it should not give you results. the correct one is `.*3`. and it should give you everything that ends with 3.

Comment: @GowriLakshmi yes you can. you can do the same thing I did to replace `,` with `|` in the given search term. so, if you want users to just right an asterik `*` instead of `.*`, this is the way: `this.value.toLowerCase().replace(',', '|').replace('*', '.*')`. Just know that this might give you unexpected problems. you can break perfectly viable regex expressions by changing too much. Maybe the best thing is to create your own search language and translate that behind the scene to regex, but separate those layers completely.

Comment: @GowriLakshmi you can use the same function I defined in my answer to do that. It's the same method. Just disable the regex in the ui search, but use the api search with regex capabilities to separate the default regex language from the search UI, but use it behind the scenes

Comment: So i have to write separate code for API search

Comment: @GowriLakshmi I suggest you go over my code and try to understand it. I **already did an [API search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) in the answer I gave you** by changing the search term and filtering the table accordingly. Take that example and change it as you please to create the syntax you want. You can pretty much override everything you want in the same function I use in my answer.

Comment: Notice that the correct regex expression to replace ALL commas is `.replace(/,/g, '|')`. updated the answer

Comment: But when i added this expression ," \wst\w "  . it is not working fine , can i get your guidance please

Comment: and if i give a comma at the end it retrieved everything again , so if accidently i give a comma at end it will show everything so the filter will be a waste

Comment: @GowriLakshmi what are you trying to get with this regex ` \wst\w`? what are you trying to find?

Comment: for example , my name " GowriLakshmi" if i search for Go% it should retrieve my Name , and even if i search %Laks% also it should return all names with Laksh in btween

Comment: @GowriLakshmi maybe you need to [freshen up on you JavaScript Regex](https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-regular-expressions-for-beginners-bb6107015d91) :-) `Go%` => `Go.*` to find your name. `%Laks%` => `.*Laks.*` should return all names with laks in between. Also notice that in my answer I replaced `.replace(',', '|')` to `.replace(/,/g, '|')` to replace **ALL** commas and not just the first one. if you used that and added you're own, you need to fix those.

Comment: i didn't replace anything .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232330/discussion-between-gowri-lakshmi-and-thatkookooguy).